# How to merge two or more Word documents

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word, documents, merge

How can I merge two or more Word documents without copying contents to one single document? Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "merge"? Are you looking for a faster way to append one to the other, or to embed documents, or something like using a diff tool to resolve conflicts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for office 2010.
1. insert menu
[image]
2. click on "text from file"
3. select the files you want to merge into this document.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question here, but it appears this method does exactly what the question states to avoid - copying the contents into a single document.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the field code (inserted by pressing Ctrl-F9) `{INCLUDETEXT "Disk:\\Path\\to\\file.docx"}`.  Note that you really do need to escape all the backslashes.